# Common function to avoid code duplication for handling 2 different type of object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, ado.net

I am fetching tables,columns from Sql server and mysql database so i am having some code duplication.

I want to keep a common function where i would like to handle both mysql and sql server connection(opening and closing) along with disposing the connection object.

**This is my common function for getting tables of Mysql and ms sql**:

```
public List<Tables> GetTables(string databaseName, string connectionString, string type)
{
    var list = new List<Tables>();
    if (type == 'mysql')
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            list = con.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
                              .Select
                                      (
                                          t => new Tables
                                          {
                                              Name = t["TABLE_SCHEMA"].ToString() + "." + t[2].ToString()
                                          }
                                      ).ToList();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            list = con.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
                             .Select
                                     (
                                         t => new Tables
                                         {
                                             Name = t["TABLE_SCHEMA"].ToString() + "." + t[2].ToString()
                                         }
                                     ).ToList();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

So i am having code duplication above and same in case of getting columns:

```
public List<Columns> GetColumns(string connectionString, string database, string table, string type)
{
    if (type == 'mysql')
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            var list = conn.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
                           .Select
                           (
                                col => new
                                {
                                   //column details 
                                }
                           ).ToList();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            var list = conn.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
                           .Select
                           (
                                col => new
                                {
                                   //column details 
                                }
                           ).ToList();
            conn.Close();
            return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So can anybody please guide me how to avoid above code duplication and keep 1 common function which will open and close connection along with disposing the connection object so that i can call it while fetching tables and columns??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `MySqlConnection` and `SqlConnection` inherits from DbConnection.

```
public List<Tables> GetTables(string databaseName, string connectionString, string type)
{
    var connection = connectionFactory.GetConnection(connectionString, type);

    return connection.GetTables(connection);
}

public List<Tables> GetColumns(string databaseName, string connectionString, string type)
{
    var connection = connectionFactory.GetConnection(connectionString, type);

    return connection.GetColumns(connection);
}

private IEnumerable<Table> GetTables(DbConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    list = con.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
              .Select(t => new Tables
              {
                   Name = t["TABLE_SCHEMA"].ToString() + "." + t[2].ToString()
              }).ToList();
    connection.Close();
 }

private IEnumerable<Table> GetColumns(DbConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    list = con.GetSchema("COLUMNS").AsEnumerable()
              .Select(t => new Tables
              {
                   Name = t["COLUMN_SCHEMA"].ToString() + "." + t[2].ToString()
              }).ToList();
    connection.Close();
 }

public class ConnectionFactory
{
     public DbConnection GetConnection(string connectionString, string type)
     {
           switch(type)
           {
                case "mysql":
                     return new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                case "mssql":
                     return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                default:
                     throw new UnsupportedException($"{type} not supported.");
           }

     }
}
```

And I am assuming that you need both connections in the same app, and that it is not just "in case I need to switch database provider". Typical you would create an implementation per database type and abstract that out by an interface.

Comment: Now i have a function of fetching columns too so in that case i would need 2 methods right??

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this.thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should encapsulate creation of connection in a separate function and just it.